# MAUI: Can't rebuild the app after installing Plugin.Firebase package

Tags: maui

I can't rebuild the app in release mode for creating APK files after the installation of `Plugin.Firebase` and `Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics`. If I remove these packages I can rebuild and create APK file.

I follow [this](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e) blog and they already suggesting to install 2 packages to prevent build errors. I did that too, still getting a lot of errors.

[image]

My error screenshot:

[image]

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 from 1.7.20.1 to 1.7.10. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> MyApp -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime 2.5.2.1 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.Ktx 2.5.1.1 -> Xamarin.KotlinX.Coroutines.Android 1.6.4.1 -> Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 (>= 1.7.20.1)
> MyApp -> Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 (>= 1.7.10)    MyApp   E:\My Projects\MAUI\listpm-requester-app-maui\MyApp\MyApp.csproj    1

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Users.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpcpp.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\grpcpp.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\upb-generated\envoy\api\v2\core\http_uri.upb.h" because it was not found.    MyApp   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   4879

I went through their [GitHub page](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen), I didn't find any similar issues. Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved when i changed the TargetFramework to android only for windows machine. It's works for me because the iOS platform can't able to build on the Windows Machine. it's requires the MAC machine.

.csproj file add this code..

- **net7.0-android;**

Answer (score 0):

**First error:** try to update the Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8 package to the latest version (1.7.20.1 or other) in your project.

**Second error:** try to install the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudFirestore package (8.10.0.3) in your project and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Tried this, still same errors.

Comment: Could you please check this demo project? https://drive.google.com/file/d/12d-HgkNwY1CdkfUnqyWB15-5NMkA1GBX/view

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this not too long ago - the problem is that the file path for the xamarin.firebase.ios.* packages are too long (exceeds Windows' path limit restrictions).

Thankfully, the CLI doesn't care about the file path length.

The solution I have been using is to use `dotnet add package Plugin.Firebase` for initial installation, and then `dotnet build` once to set up the app. From then on, debugging the app should work as normal.

When 'archiving' your app, I then use `dotnet publish` (it seems to re-download necessary packages when archiving, and will throw errors using the UI.

[Related issue](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/65)

Comment: I have installed the packages by editing the `project.csproj` file directly, is that the reason?

Comment: Adding to the `project.csproj` file will only tell the project that it uses that package, and to try download the package if not found. The error occurs when it tries to download the package off this instruction. What we need to do is get the package downloaded and installed so it can bypass the issue.

Comment: I have removed the packages from `project.csproj` and added it back using commands like you suggest.  Installed 2 packages: `dotnet add ProjectName package Plugin.Firebase` and dotnet add `ProjectName package Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics`. After that I did `dotnet build`, but I am getting 239 Warning(s) and 370 Error(s).

Comment: Could you please check this demo project? https://drive.google.com/file/d/12d-HgkNwY1CdkfUnqyWB15-5NMkA1GBX/view

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, fixed with following ways:

Add these into your ITEM-GROUP:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference" Version="1.2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.10.0.1" />
```

And if still having error, then Please remove ios framework from csProject if you are working on WINDOWS.